# Entity Framework Core Query Specific Model both directions

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Let me preface this question with, I am VERY new to ASP.NET Core/EF Core.

My model look like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class DeviceContext : DbContext
    {
        public DeviceContext(DbContextOptions<DeviceContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DeviceLocation> DeviceLocations { get; set; }

    }

    public class Device
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
        public string WiredIPAddress { get; set; }
        public string WirelessIPAddress { get; set; }
        public DeviceLocation DeviceLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeviceLocation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to fetch a specific Device based on DeviceName, but I would also like to fetch ALL the devices in a particular Location.

I think the following would work for the first question:

```
 var _Devices = DeviceContext.Devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DeviceName == "BLA");
```

I am just having a hard time getting the second query to run. Ideally, the output would be rendered to JSON to be consumed by an API. I would like the output to look something like this:

```
{
    "Locations": {
        "NYC": ["ABC", "123"],
        "Boston": ["DEF", "456"],
        "Chicago": ["GHI", "789"]
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I use the following code, it give me the following error:

Code:

```
 // Grouping by ProfileName
 var devices = DeviceContext.DeviceLocations.Include(n => n.Device).ToList();

 var result = new { success = true, message = "Successfully fetched Devices", data = devices };
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Error:

```
  Additional information: Self referencing loop detected for property 'DeviceLocation' with type 'Project.Models.DeviceLocation'. Path 'data[0].Device[0]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

**Note :** Use Eager Loading with `Include`.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var devicesList = DeviceContext.DeviceLocations.Where(d=>d.Location = "Your-Location-Name")
                               .Include(p => p.Devices)
                               .ToList();
```

**Update :**

```
var devicesList = DeviceContext.DeviceLocations
                               .Include(p => p.Devices)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: This will pull a single location, how would you pull all of the Locations with their devices?

Comment: please see the **Update**